# Angular Animations: Wait another trigger to finish before start

Tags: angular, animation

I have a situation where I try to use Angular Animations to change the content in a div. A reproduction if it is available on https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-mclaren-4vj2hi

The only issue is that these animations are not sequentially. For example, the first time when you're going to use the codesandbox, you will see that the `#item 1` is shown. When I press on `Control` button, `#item 1` is disappearing, but in parallel `#item 2` is appearing. I expect that `#item 1` should disappear first, and after it, the `#item 2` will appear.

How I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have two options you can create a sequence animation , I will link the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/complex-animation-sequences)

**Or**

You can use the [Animation trigers](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers) , basically when #item1 animations ends you set the state to show the #item2

Comment: Is not very clear the answer. I also tried with `sequence`, but it looks like an internal animation sequence, not for other components.